# What is this macro?

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-1.8

In `ruby.h`, there are a lot of function macros defined like this:

```
static inline int
    #if defined(HAVE_PROTOTYPES)
    rb_type(VALUE obj)
    #else
    rb_type(obj)
       VALUE obj;
    #endif
    {
        if (FIXNUM_P(obj)) return T_FIXNUM;
        if (obj == Qnil) return T_NIL;
        if (obj == Qfalse) return T_FALSE;
        if (obj == Qtrue) return T_TRUE;
        if (obj == Qundef) return T_UNDEF;
        if (SYMBOL_P(obj)) return T_SYMBOL;
        return BUILTIN_TYPE(obj);
    }
```

If `HAVE_PROTOTYPES==1`, from my understanding, this function will be like this:

```
static inline int rb_type(VALUE obj)
{
   ...
}
```

Yet, if `HAVE_PROPOTYPES==0`, the function definition will be like this:

```
static inline int rb_type(VALUE obj)
      VALUE obj;
{
    ...
}
```

I don't understand if this is grammatically correct. How should I understand it?

Comment: It will be `static inline int rb_type(obj)` not `(VALUE obj)` by the way.

Comment: Whether `HAVE_PROTOTYPES` is 0 or 1, it is still defined.

Comment: It is K&R declaration style

Comment: Please tag Ruby 1.8 questions accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

```
static inline int rb_type(VALUE obj)
      VALUE obj;    # what the hack is this?
{
    ...
}
```

This is K&R C. Nobody uses it anymore. It has been deprecated for 20 years at least.

Long time ago function definitions were written like this:

```
int myfunc(myparam)
  int myparam;
{
   ...
}
```

instead of

```
int myfunc(int myparam)
{
   ...
}
```

So `HAVE_PROTOTYPES` will always be defined on any decent compiler.